# Accessing photo properties from mobile device photo library in Corona/Lua?

Tags: android, ios, lua, coronasdk

Using Corona/Lua, is it possible to select photos from the devices(android, iOS) photo library that have a certain property? For example, only select pictures which contain a certain string in the filename or only select pictures of a certain size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Corona does not do much with the photo library yet, the lastest release is the first version more or less that can even write to photo library, complex reading like that is not supported at all yet (maybe because iOS and Android have very different photo libraries, and thus this is certainly not easy to code, and it is not a feature that is critical like others in the queue)